# I cannot fetch the value of a mysql alias

Tags: mysql, php

I have the following code:

```
$query =  "
SELECT  distance, outcodepostcodes.lat, outcodepostcodes.lng
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  $table.*, outcodepostcodes.lat, outcodepostcodes.lng ,
                outcodepostcodes.lat*3 AS distance
            FROM  $table
            LEFT JOIN  outcodepostcodes
                  ON UPPER($table.postcode)=outcodepostcodes.outcode 
      ) AS x
    WHERE  $where_no_and
      AND  (hide='0'  OR  hide IS NULL  OR  hide='')
      AND  distance <= 20
    ORDER BY  rent $reihenach
    LIMIT  $offset, $rowsPerPage 
";
```

When I do a:

```
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) 
{
  $id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
  etc, etc;
  $distance=mysql_result($result,$i,"distance");
}
```

$distance is empty

Any help appreciated

Comment: What do you mean "empty" - is it NULL? 0? Provide a SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table(s)\G - and show us the SQL string as submitted to the RDBMS, not the PHP code - that's more of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Use PDO instead, then iterate over the arrayed resultset. No idea why you've coded it like that.

Comment: The query seems to be syntactically wrong. You have `SELECT distance, outcodepostcodes.lat, outcodepostcodes.lng` but in that level there is only the (derived) table `x`. The `outcodepostcodes.` should give you a syntax error.

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_*` API; switch to `mysqli_*` or PDO.